When to play animations in Godot 4 (GDScript)
When should I play animations and how to make sure an animation is finished before a different one is played. I am currently having a problem with my "punch" animation that only plays for a split second before it reverts back to the idle animation. This code is mostly testing things out so it is quite messy and I apologise.
extends CharacterBody2D

const SPEED = 130.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -600.0

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

@onready var animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D
@onready var collision_top = $CollisionShape2DTop
@onready var raycast_crouch_1 = $RayCast2DCrouch1
@onready var raycast_crouch_2 = $RayCast2DCrouch2
@onready var hitbox = $AreaHitbox

var health = 100
var was_on_floor = false
var was_jumping_up = false
var land_timer = 0.0
var is_crouching = false
var crouching_under = false

var enemy_attack = false
var attack_cooldown = true
var alive = true

var is_punching = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    update_health()
    enemy_is_attacking()
    
    if health <= 0:
        alive = false
        get_tree().reload_current_scene()
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    # Handle jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("crouch") and is_on_floor():
        crouch()
    elif Input.is_action_just_released("crouch"):
            if can_stand():
                stand()
            else:
                if not crouching_under:
                    crouching_under = true
        
    if crouching_under and  can_stand() and not Input.is_action_pressed("crouch"):
        stand()
        crouching_under = false
    
    # Get the input direction: -1, 0, 1
    var direction = Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right")
    
    # Flip the sprite
    if direction > 0:
        animated_sprite.flip_h = false
    elif direction < 0:
        animated_sprite.flip_h = true

        # Handle punch
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("punch"):
        
        is_punching = true
    
    # Determine animation state
    if is_punching:
        animated_sprite.play("punch")
        is_punching = false  # Punch animation is over
    elif is_on_floor() and not is_punching:
        if not was_on_floor:
            animated_sprite.play("land")
            land_timer = 0.1  # Play land animation for 0.1 seconds
        elif land_timer > 0:
            land_timer -= delta
        elif direction == 0:
            if is_crouching:
                animated_sprite.play("crouch")
            else:
                animated_sprite.play("idle")
        else:
            if is_crouching:
                animated_sprite.play("crouch")
            else:
                animated_sprite.play("run")
        was_on_floor = true
        was_jumping_up = false

    else:
        if velocity.y < 0:
            if not was_jumping_up:
                animated_sprite.play("jump_up")
                was_jumping_up = true
        elif velocity.y > -100 and velocity.y < 100:
            animated_sprite.play("jump_max")
        else:
            animated_sprite.play("jump_down")
        was_on_floor = false

    # Handle movement
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()
    
func can_stand() -> bool:
    var result = not raycast_crouch_1.is_colliding() and not raycast_crouch_2.is_colliding()
    return result
    
func crouch():
        if is_crouching:
            return
        collision_top.disabled = true
        is_crouching = true

func stand():
    if is_crouching == false:
        return 
    collision_top.disabled = false
    is_crouching = false

func update_health():
    var health_bar = $HealthBar
    health_bar.value = health
    if health >= 100:
        health_bar.visible = false
    else:
        health_bar.visible = true
    
func player():
    pass
        
func _on_regen_timer_timeout():
    if health < 100:
        health = health + 10
        if health > 100:
            health = 100
    elif health <= 0:
        health = 0

func enemy_is_attacking():
    if enemy_attack and attack_cooldown:
        health -= 20
        attack_cooldown = false
        $DamageCooldown.start()
        print(health)

func _on_damage_cooldown_timeout():
    attack_cooldown = true


func _on_area_hitbox_body_entered(body):
    print("Entered")
    enemy_attack = true


func _on_area_hitbox_body_exited(body):
    if body.has_method("enemy"):
        enemy_attack = false


I tried adding timers, conditions, etc. but I cant seem to figure it out and I am not sure what is the right way. I have seen multiple examples using different methods on how to do it so I am not sure which is the right way.

You should investigate signals: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_signal.html AnimationSprite2D has several signals that it emits when various events occur in the animation lifecycle.  You could use those to manage your animation transition logic (look at the Signals section): https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite2d.html

Your animation will immediately finish, because you reset your is_punching variable to early. The play function of the AnimationSprite will not hold your code till the animation is finished. So by setting is_punching false there your code will branch into your normal behaviour on the next call.
Instead you can use the signals of the AnimatedSprite. It has the signal animation_finished which is called every time a animation ends. You can connect a function to it through the editor in the right tree in the tab "Node".
Or connect it through code like this (I did it in the ready function):
func _ready():   
    animated_sprite.animation_finished.connect(self._on_animated_sprite_2d_animation_finished)

In the function you can check, if the animation was your "punch" animation. And if so reset your boolean:
func _on_animated_sprite_2d_animation_finished():
    if animated_sprite.animation == "punch":
        is_punching = false

The rest of your code can stay the same to have a working punch animation. Just remove the is_punching = false part from the loop:
# Determine animation state
if is_punching:
    animated_sprite.play("punch")
elif is_on_floor() and not is_punching:


Hey, thank you for your advice. I tried it, but for some reason the on_anmated_sprite_2d_animation_finished() function never gets called. I have made sure its properly connected, but it just wouldn't execute and I have no idea how to fix it

hmm odd, I tried the code I provided to assure, that I wrote the connect function correctly. You could try to add the signal through the editor as descriped above. Did you set an breakpoint to check if the signal is called, or did nothing happen?
